# What did they do to get -2/3 as the constant for this integral?

Tags: integration

Find the integral of:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1-3\sqrt{x})}dx$$

So far I know to substitute $u = (1-3\sqrt{x})$ and $du = \frac{-3}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$ but I'm not sure what to do with the $\sqrt{x}$ in the denominator. I tried splitting it up but I got the wrong answer compared to Wolfram Alpha. They got:

$$\frac{-2}{3}ln|1-3\sqrt{x}|+C$$

I know I have a $\frac{-3}{2}$ from $du$ but I'm not sure how to plug that in with the $\sqrt{x}$ being in the denominator.

Comment: The $\sqrt{x}$ in the denominator is what makes the problem easy! $-\frac{2}{3} du = \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$, leading you to the integral $\frac{-2}{3}\int \frac{du}{u}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier to see if you regroup your terms like
$$
\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1-3\sqrt{x})}\,dx=-\frac{2}{3}\int\frac{1}{(1-3\sqrt{x})}\color{red}{\frac{-3}{2\sqrt{x}}\,dx}=-\frac{2}{3}\int\frac{1}{u}\color{red}{\,du}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! From there on I just use the property and got the right answer.